# Can only get one of two custom menus to display

Tags: menus

I'm a wordpress beginner and at the moment struggling to get to grips with custom menus. I have created two menus. Wordpress tells me the theme supports two menus. I have

```
<?php wp_nav_menu('menu=services_menu'); ?>
```

Where I want one menu to appear. I have

```
<?php wp_nav_menu('menu=left_navigation'); ?>
```

Where I want the other menu to appear.

I have

```
<?php
if ( function_exists( 'register_nav_menus' ) ) {
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
          'services_menu' => 'Services menu',
          'left_navigation' => 'Left vertical navigation Menu'
        )
    );
}
?>
```

In functions.php.

Both menus appear under "Appearance -> menus ->Theme locations" and are associated correctly. But only the services menu ever appears, in both locations. I've read a welter of different solutions to doing this, none of which seem to have any result other than the one described above. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I seem to have now solved this myself. Perhaps there are many different ways of doing this and I happened to get two different ways mixed up. I'm not sure, but I have now found a different example in the codex and got it working.

Comment: You should post the solution that you found, as an **answer**, so that others can benefit from what you found. WPSE is a *shared information/resource* site, not a typical support forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that [`wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) should really only *ever* be calling **`theme_location`**, *not* `menu`.

The Theme defines **menu locations**, and then places those menu locations in the template. The **user** defines *menus*, and *assigns menus to theme locations*.

So, change this:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu('menu=services_menu'); ?>
```

...to this:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( 'theme_location=services_menu' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'menu name' )); ?>
```

possibly?

Comment: Er, yup :o) I noticed though that if you trash pages, they are still appearing in the menu (although you get a 404 if you click on the link) - is that a known bug or something wrong with what I have done?

Comment: Hmm, mine doesn't do that (with auto-generated page list)... is this for an auto generated menu?  Or a custom made one?  Possibly with custom made menus, anything you add manually you have to delete manually?

Comment: yeah it's a custom one has "add new top level pages automatically" ticked. You'd think if it added them automatically it would also remove them automatically..